# query for searching array in elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

in elasticsearch (5.3)

my document structure has three field is like this :

```
{
  x:55
  y:66
  z:44
}
```

i need query for searching this array is in my documents:

```
 [[55,66,44],[45,68,95]]
```

equivalent in SQL language :

```
  select * from table where (x=55 AND y=66 AND z=44) OR (x=45 AND y=68 AND z=95)
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, you should consider being more specific and adding more detail.  On StackOverflow it's also generally accepted that you should try something/anything before posting a question so you're not simply asking the community to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "x": 55
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "y": 66
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "z": 44
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "x": 45
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "y": 68
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "z": 95
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't want to search Separately .

Comment: In your SQL you're searching seperately